# Div, z-index, opacity. Bug, feature or user relate issue?

Tags: css, z-index, opacity

Hi I have a problem with an CSS opacity line breaking intended output.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ztm35/)

Z-index on red div is 1, the blue has 206. 
Now, remove from CSS  (or change to 1.0).`#menu {opacity: 0.8;}`

Working as intended.

Can someone explain this?

Or more importantly how I make my darker div on top, while having a semi transparent div?
I'm not a CSS expert so it is quite possibly a user error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with an unexpected **[stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context)** being established by `#menu`.

To quote [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/):

> A stacking context is formed, anywhere in the document, by any element
>   which is either
>
> - the root element (HTML),
> - positioned (absolutely or relatively) with a z-index value other than    "auto",
> - **elements with an opacity value less than 1.**

This is the reason your div is behaving unexpectedly when you apply an opacity < 1 to it. `#menu` now establishes a separate stacking context, and the z-index of its descendant `#status` has no meaning outside of this context. To correct this problem, apply the z-index to `#menu` itself.

Comment: I... Uhh... You quote the what? yeah yeah Ill google it. I understood your last sentance and that did the trick. I... uhh... Wow! Thank!!

Comment: @Tobis tl;dr z-index only works reliably for siblings. `#menu` and `#input` are siblings, `#status` and `#input` are not.

Comment: Definitely not a tl;dr, I'm reading. Just never found that resource before. It's a bit over my head though but ill bookmark it for future use. Have any more goodies while you're here? :) Thanks again for your time!

Comment: @Tobis That's all I can think of for now. If you're just starting out with CSS, SitePoint is a great resource.